# Criteria api fetch object from ancestor

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

is there any change to fetch object from ancestor? I have these entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SPORT")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "sport_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 32)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Sport implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "sport_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String sportType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HEAD_ID", referencedColumnName = "IDENT")
    @ToStringExclude
    protected Headquaters headquaters;

}




@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Constants.COST_REPORT_CODE)
public class HandSport extends Sport {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COST_TRADE_ID", referencedColumnName = "TRADE_ID")
    private Playground Playground;


}
```

from these entities I have generated this metamodel

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(HandSport.class)
public abstract class HandSport_ extends com.test.entity.Sport_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<HandSport, Playground> playground;
}

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Sport.class)
public abstract class Sport_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Sport, Headquaters> headquaters;   
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Sport, String> id;


}
```

And now I can fetch only playground:

```
EntityGraph<HandSport> fetchGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(HandSport.class);
fetchGraph.addSubgraph(HandSport_.playground);
select.distinct(true);
TypedQuery<HandSport> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(select)
.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", fetchGraph);
```

Why I cannot add

```
fetchGraph.addSubgraph(Sport_.headquters);
```

If I do it I can see compile error:

```
"Cannot resolve method 'addSubgraph(javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute<com.test.entity.Sport, com.test.entity.Headquateres>)'"
```

is there any change to fetch values from ancestor? Or Is it possible to create a second FetchGraph and register two graphs by hint?

Comment: do you get any error message?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - There is no error message, it can't be compiled. it is underline by red and with note "Cannot resolve method 'addSubgraph(javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute<com.test.entity.Sport, com.test.entity.Headquateres>)'" - I added this to my question

Answer (score 0):

The JPA API has incorrect usage of generics in various methods of the `EntityGraph` class.
This was [reported to the JPA "expert group"](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/112) back in 2015, but they have not bothered to fix it.

DataNucleus JPA publishes their own JPA API jar, and they did fix it for their users some time ago, but since you are using Hibernate then that won't benefit you.